# How do I load a file from the config folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the [evernote gem](https://github.com/cgs/evernote) to access the Evernote API. In those instructions, it says to create a config file containing the API account details, and then load the config file as follows:

```
config = File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/config.yml"
user_store = Evernote::UserStore.new(user_store_url, config, "sandbox")
```

I created a file `evernote.yml` in the config folder, and put the following code in the `home` action in `pages_controller.rb`

```
config = File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/evernote.yml"
user_store = Evernote::UserStore.new(user_store_url, config, "sandbox")
```

When the code is run, I get this error on the 2nd line

```
Errno::ENOENT in PagesController#home
No such file or directory - /Users/ben/rails_projects/evernote_app/app/controllers/evernote.yml
```

How do I load the config file without getting this error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that `File.dirname(__FILE__)` points to the directory of the current file, which happens to be a controller. You want to point to config directory under your rails root. To make this work I would do the following:

```
config = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'evernote.yml')
user_store = Evernote::UserStore.new(user_store_url, config, "sandbox")
```

Comment: You can also use `Rails.root.join('config', 'evernote.yml')`, since `Rails.root` is a `Pathname` object.

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
config_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml"
# or this to load yaml directly
config = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml"))
```

`Rails.root` gives you the path of Rails application root folder

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Rails, since 4.2 there's a builtin way to do that:

```
config = Rails.application.config_for(:evernote)
```

Source: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/the-lesser-known-features-in-rails-4-dot-2

Answer (score 1):

I have the need for a config is just about ever Rails app I've ever worked with. Here's what I use, put this in config/application.rb in before the module definition of your application:

```
# Load config/config.yml into APP_CONFIG
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(ERB.new(IO.read(File.expand_path('../config.yml', __FILE__))).result)[Rails.env]
```

The main difference with this version is it runs the config file through ERB, which can be useful if you want to use ruby variables and stuff in the config.